# Linking Google App Engine website with custom domain

Tags: google-app-engine, dns, web

I created a website on Google App Engine and successfully deployed it to some internal Google server (someprojectname.appspot.com).

I bought a new domain from Marcaria.com (mydomain.com) and I want to make this my main website.

In Google App Engine, when I try to verify a new domain it gives me CNAME field to be added from where I bought the domain.

When I go to Marcaria and try to link, it ask me for Primary and Secondary names to be added. Any idea from where can I get this information for Google and how can I link my own website?

Answer (score 0):

According to [Marcaria site](https://support.marcaria.com/hc/en-us/articles/215525423-Set-up-DNS-Servers) the primary and secondary default DNS servers are:

`DNS1: ns01.trademarkarea.com`

`DNS2: ns02.trademarkarea.com`

Those names are implicitly given by them and there is no need to change them.

To [map your new custom domain to Google App Engine application](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/mapping-custom-domains) you need to [add the CNAME record](https://support.marcaria.com/hc/en-us/articles/215528083-How-do-I-create-an-A-MX-or-CNAME-record-) provided by the domain verification process, to your registrar (in this case Macaria.com)